# Encoding issues with python's etree.tostring

Tags: python, xml, utf-8, tostring

I'm using python 2.6.2's xml.etree.cElementTree to create an xml document:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
elem = etree.Element('tag')
elem.text = (u"Würth Elektronik Midcom").encode('utf-8')
xml = etree.tostring(elem,encoding='UTF-8')
```

At the end of the day, xml looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<tag>W&#195;&#188;rth Elektronik Midcom</tag>
```

It looks like tostring ignored the encoding parameter and encoded 'ü' into some other character encoding ('ü' is a valid utf-8 encoding, I'm fairly sure).

Any advice as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're encoding the text twice. Try this:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
elem = etree.Element('tag')
elem.text = u"Würth Elektronik Midcom"
xml = etree.tostring(elem, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Answer (score 5):

`etree.tostring(elem, encoding=str)`

will return `str` but not `binary` in Python 3

> You can also serialise to a Unicode string without declaration by
>           passing the `unicode` function as encoding (or `str` in Py3),
>           or the name 'unicode'.  This changes the return value from a byte
>           string to an unencoded unicode string.

Comment: bytes are returned, not str